# How to connect two instances of netcat through a veth device pair?

Tags: debian, networking, ip, netcat, namespace

I want to connect to instances of `netcat` through a veth(4) device pair.

Thus, I create the veth pair using `ip` as follows:

```
ip link add eth0 type veth peer name eth1
ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev eth0
ip addr add 10.0.0.2/24 dev eth1
ip addr show eth0
13: eth0@eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000                                                           
    link/ether 8a:74:8f:e7:dd:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 
ip addr show eth1
14: eth1@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000                                                              
    link/ether a2:7e:07:be:9a:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

In the above, I need to assign the veth devices an IP address, since `netcat` will only listen on an IP address, not a raw network device.

However, after starting a `netcat` listener on eth0 in a terminal and attempting to connect to it from another terminal, I receive no connection in the first terminal:

```
netcat -n -vvvv -l -s 10.0.0.1 -p 8080
netcat -n -vvv 10.0.0.1 8080 # timeout
netcat -n -vvv 10.0.0.2 8080 # timeout
```

Looking in the routing table, it seems that `ip` created rules for the veth pair automatically:

```
ip route 
default via 10.211.55.1 dev enp0s5 proto static metric 100 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also you did something you didn't write in the question: routes's hinted sources for eth0 and eth1 are inverted

Comment: @A.B - thank you. Still shouldn’t it work with the each veth being in a separate network namespace?

Comment: @A.B - I fixed the routing.

Comment: Is your lo interface up?

Comment: @A.B - why would the traffic use the lo interface, when the IP is not 127.0.0.1? LAN traffic is sometimes in the 10.0.0.0/8, and don’t use lo? No, I didn’t disable iptables. Yes, lo should be up, since I run this in the root network namespace. TBH, I’m not a network expert, just wanted to test veth in action. Didn’t thought it would be this difficult. Would you be able to provide a working PoC for using veth interfaces with netcat? I would be grateful, been struggling for hours.

Comment: I realize the question is still not reflecting reality. veth interfaces are created down, but they are displayed UP. So the question doesn't reflect what was done. I'll leave it here

Comment: Sorry, I left those commands out of the question for brevity. I know how to bring interfaces up with `ip link <device> up`

Comment: veth pairs are really meant to connect network namespaces, so it'll be a lot easier if you put one (or both) ends into a different network namespaces. To be able to do it in the same namespace, you need `netcat` to bind on a particular interface, and I am not sure which of the many versions of `netcat` supports that.

Comment: @dirkt - I see they are meant to be put in different network namespaces, but can you tell me why it doesn’t work in a single namespace, when both veth pairs have been assigned IP addresses? In that case netcat is able to listen on the device? Is it a matter of routing that’s not set up correctly? If the ends are put in different namespaces, I still need to assign them IP addresses for netcat being able to listen and connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see they are meant to be put in different network namespaces, but can you tell me why it doesn’t work in a single namespace, when both veth pairs have been assigned IP addresses?

The following things likely all go wrong:

- An application listening to an address will process *any* incoming packet for this address, no matter where it comes from. So the packet could come from either end, or even from a completely different network interface (e.g. `eth0`).
- If the Linux kernel detects a destination address that is local, it will process this as a local packet, so it will never go through the veth-pair.
- If the Linux kernel packet detects an incoming packet with a local source address that is not local (i.e., comes through the veth-pair), it considers this a routing error, because under normal circumstances this means there's a routing loop somewhere in the network. To avoid network flooding, this packet gets dropped.

The same things would happen if your computer had two LAN network interfaces (`eth0` and `eth1`), and you connect them with a LAN-cable.

So, if you want to play with veth-pairs, create network namespaces.

Comment: Thank you. How does the Linux kernel detects a destination address that is local? Is an address local, if an application is listening on that address (ie. some interface has been assigned that address), or does it consider all the reserved IP-ranges as local (eg. 10.0.0.0/8)? A packet processed as a local packet, means the packet will not go through any interface (not even lo), but gets delivered directly to the application? Any packet that goes through an interface is not considered local?

Comment: All these technicalities you seem to understand and master, where have you learned them? I don’t think the man pages provide such insight.

Comment: I don’t see how you first list item can go wrong? No other applications are sending netcat any traffic.

Comment: And how can list item 2 and 3 happen simultaneously?

Comment: That's enough for 5 other questions... An address is local if it's assigned to any network interface. It doesn't matter if an application is using it,or not. A local-to-local packet will always go through `lo`, even if the destination address is not `127.0.0.1` (try `tcpdump -i lo` and `ping` local address). 2 and 3 can't happen simultaneously. Man pages only document commands, you need kernel and networking documentation.

Comment: Thanks, @dirkt. Your answer suggests that 2 and 3 could happen simultaneously by “*all go wrong*”. Should I read documentation on kernel.org for more insight into kernel networking?

Comment: I meant "even if you fix one of those items, then the other will go wrong". If you are looking for *advanced* networking, read e.g. [policy routing](http://www.policyrouting.org/PolicyRoutingBook/ONLINE/TOC.html), [this](http://www.gremwell.com/linux-routing-quirks), `Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt` in the kernel source (`accept_local`, `route_localnet`, `rp_filter`), and also look at iptables/ebtables, summary [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg).

Comment: Thanks @dirkt, I appreciate your compiled list of resources!